# É possível agrupar um intervalo de valores?

Tags: mysql, sql

Fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
`select t.net, t.hora, t.`data`, t.`local` from domingos t
join(
select net, updated, count(*) from domingos
where `data` = '07/05/2017'
group by updated, net
having count(*) > 4
) as u
on t.updated = u.updated
and t.net = u.net
group by t.net, t.hora, t.`data`, t.`local`
order by hora;`
```

Esta consulta me retorna os valores na figura abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe algum parâmetro para o group by que torna possível agrupar os valores da coluna `hora` considerando, por exemplo, que os valores de 00:34:00 a 00:36:00 sejam representados por apenas um valor?

Comment: aí você teria que truncar a hora, para a forma que queira, ou criar um case para sua condição.

Comment: Não, pois horários diferentes se referem a dispositivos diferentes, mas dispositivos diferentes podem ter a mesma 'net'. Agrupar por net me faria perder a informação acerca do número de dispositivos. Entende?

Comment: Ok... vou postar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT t.net, u.hh, t.`data`, t.`local`
FROM domingos t
JOIN (
    SELECT net, updated, HOUR(hora) AS hh, COUNT(*)
    FROM domingos
    WHERE `data` = '07/05/2017'
    GROUP BY updated, net
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
) AS u
ON t.updated = u.updated
AND t.net = u.net
GROUP BY t.net, u.hh, t.`data`, t.`local`
ORDER BY hora;
```

Ou seja, ao invés de usar `t.hora` no `GROUP BY` e no `SELECT`, use o `u.hh` que é o `HOUR(hora)`.

Comment: Se não me engano o `t.hora` não pode ficar no `select` se não vai listar todos.:)

Comment: @Marconi No banco de dados existe vários valores repetidos para `hora`, usei o group by para saber apenas um deles, assim como as outras colunas.

Comment: @Marconi Tem razão. Editei a resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa creio eu ser esta a resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Está dando erro quando uso HOUR(t.hora) no `group by`. Quando uso apenas no `select` dá resultado. Entretanto, o resultado é apenas a hora, ou seja, desconsidera os minutos e segundos, o agrupamento por hora iria me fazer perder informações. Há como agrupar por minutos?

Comment: @FrankQueiroz Resposta editada. Me diga se funciona assim. Quanto aos minutos, você pode colocar também um campo para o `MINUTE(hora)`.

Comment: Perfeito! No código acima só falta colocar `hour(hora)` no `group by` e `hh` no `order by` que funciona perfeitamente. Com a dica do `minute(hora)` meu problema será resolvido.